# first order equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a first order PDE with the initial condition:  
(a) 
$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}-\displaystyle(xt)\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$$
$$f(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}, \hspace{1cm}x\in \mathbb {R}$$

(b)
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}-\displaystyle{b}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}+cf=0\hspace{2.5cm}$  on$\hspace{0.3cm}\mathbb {R} \times {\{t=0\}}$
$f=g, \hspace{7.1cm}$  on$\hspace{0.3cm}\mathbb {R} \times {\{t=0\}}$

I will try to solve this

Comment: Have you tried the method of characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

(a)

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-xt=-xs$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=x_0e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}=x_0e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$\dfrac{df}{ds}=0$ , letting $f(0)=F(x_0)$ , we have $f(x,t)=F(x_0)=F\left(xe^\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$

$f(x,0)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ :

$F(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

$\therefore f(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2e^{t^2}}$

(b)

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-b$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=x_0-bs=x_0-bt$

$\dfrac{df}{ds}=-cf$ , letting $f(0)=F(x_0)$ , we have $f(x,t)=F(x_0)e^{-cs}=F(x+bt)e^{-ct}$